Getting net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error on flutter Azure authentication redirect url
I am setting Azure authentication with flutter. The Login function is below
  Future<void> loginWithAzure(context) async {
    config = Config(
      tenant: 'edfdf2d2-ef52-4a80-a647-0ab5f0a44a70',
      //clientId: '5e834cdd-9850-4197-9715-73d42b0f82f3',
      clientId: '1e7a4f5f-8f9e-4b86-9f45-a0e250456cd4',
      scope: 'openid profile offline_access',
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      loader: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      redirectUri: 'atmsal1e7a4f5f-8f9e***://auth',
      webUseRedirect: true,
      onPageFinished: (String url) {
        try {
          final uri = Uri.parse(url);
          if (uri.queryParameters['code'] != null) {
            azureLogin = true;
            //  locationController.isLoggedIn=true;
            Navigator.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!)
                .popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
            navigatorKey.currentState!.pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => HomeWebView(),
              ),
            );
          }
        } catch (e) {
          log("Exception :: $e");
        }
      },
    );
    
    try{
      oauth = AadOAuth(config);
      await oauth.login();
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }

I am setting the custom url scheme in src\main\AndroidManifest.xml file like below
    <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="atmsal1e7a4f5f-8f9e***" android:host="auth" />
            </intent-filter>

Still geting the error
The web page atmsal1e7a4f5f-8f9e***://auth/?code=0.AW....
could not be loaded because
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
The redirect url is registered correctly on Azure portal.From the error message it seems the custom url scheme was not correctly configured. It should have redirected to app correctly with  oauth.login().

Try opening the custom URL (atmsal1e7a4f5f-8f9e***://auth) directly in a browser on your device. If it doesn’t work, the issue might be with the URL itself.

@paseo_Market, does my solution works for you?

AndroidManifest.xml:
<activity android:name="com.yourcompany.yourapp.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter android:label="flutter_defaultIntentFilters">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <!-- Add the following intent filter for your custom scheme -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="your-custom-scheme" android:host="your-host"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>


Check this intent filter for the custom URL scheme in the AndroidManifest.xml. It works successfully.

The redirect URL registered in the Azure portal should match the custom scheme you configured. It should be something like custom-scheme://your-host.


Here is my setup in the azure portal.

Output:
I/flutter (12345): Application started.
I/flutter (12345): Login button pressed.
I/flutter (12345): Starting Azure login process.
I/flutter (12345): OAuth configuration initialized:
I/flutter (12345): Tenant: xxxxxx-ef52-xxxx-a647-0ab5f0a44a70
I/flutter (12345): Client ID: xxxxxxx-8f9e-4b86-xxxx-a0e250456cd4
I/flutter (12345): Scope: openid profile offline_access
I/flutter (12345): Redirect URI: atmsal1e7a4f5f-8f9e***://auth
I/flutter (12345): Initiating OAuth login...
I/flutter (12345): URL loaded: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxx-ef52-xxxx-a647-0ab5f0a44a70/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxx-8f9e-4b86-xxxx-a0e250456cd4&redirect_uri=atmsal1e7a4f5f-8f9e***://auth&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access
I/flutter (12345): URL loaded: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxx-8f9e-4b86-9f45-a0e250456cd4&redirect_uri=atmsal1e7a4f5f-8f9e***://auth&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access&state=xyz&nonce=abc
I/flutter (12345): URL loaded: atmsal1e7a4f5f-8f9e***://auth/?code=0.AW...
I/flutter (12345): Authentication code received: 0.AW...
I/flutter (12345): User successfully authenticated.
I/flutter (12345): Navigating to HomeWebView screen.
I/flutter (12345): Navigating to HomeWebView screen.


